# What does s.recvfrom_nonblock(65536)[0] do in this code snippet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hi could someone explain what does s.recvfrom_nonblock(65536)[0]  mean in the following code snippet as I checked https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/UDPSocket.html but it didn't make sense to me

```
require 'socket'

s = UDPSocket.new

s.bind('127.0.0.1', 8100)
while true do
  begin
    line = s.recvfrom_nonblock(65536)[0]
        puts line if line.include?('test1') || line.include?('test2') || line.include?('somestring')
  rescue IO::WaitReadable
    IO.select([s])
    retry
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`#recvfrom_nonblock` will receive data from udpsocket, and return an array of information about that data. The argument provided (65536) is the maximum number of bytes to accept from the message, and index 0 of the returned array contains the actual "message".

So in short, your code snippet accepts up to 65536 bytes of data over port 8100 via recvfrom_nonblock. The recvfrom_nonblock method will return an array of information, but all that this snippet cares about is index 0 of that array, which contains the text being passed, and saves it to the `line` variable.

If you take a look at the [example in the rubydoc](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/UDPSocket.html#method-i-recvfrom_nonblock), it has a comment in the code that demonstrates what the array output looks like.

Comment: You could also decompose the returned array: `line, addr = s.recvfrom_nonblock(65536)`